# CMake add_custom_command does not find file

Tags: cmake

I have a example project with the structure below:

```
--SampleMinimal
----CMakeLists.txt
----main.cpp
----sample.cpp
```

and the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(sample-minimal)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT sample2.cpp
        COMMAND cp sample.cpp sample2.cpp
        DEPENDS sample.cpp)
add_executable(grpc-app-main main.cpp sample2.cpp)
```

While I build the target, I get these errors:

```
$cmake --S . -B build
$ cmake --build build
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/SL/Projects/cpp/sample_minimal/build
[ 25%] Generating sample2.cpp
cp: sample.cpp: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [sample2.cpp] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/grpc-app-main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

There exists in the project, Why does it could not find the file, why doesn't it copy the sample into the cmake-build-debug folder like other source files?

Comment: @user cmake-build-debug/grpc-demo this directory is autogenerated, other source files will be copyed into this folder automatically, but this sample.cpp file does not.why?

Comment: The commands you show and the output do not match. You configure first (which produces CMake's output), then you build (which gives make's output). Where does the message "Generating sample2.cpp" come from? Please [edit] and show your actual code.

Comment: @Friedrich hm. have you ever used custom commands? See the definition of `cmLocalGenerator::ConstructComment` in https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmLocalGenerator.cxx

Comment: @user "have you ever used custom commands?" a pity you could not do without this.

Answer (score 2):

The default working directory for running the command of `add_custom_command` is the directory in the build tree corresponding to the current `CMakeLists.txt`. This means the command isn't be able to find the file via the relative path `sample.cpp` and it wouldn't copy the file to a location where it can be found by the executable target as `sample2.cpp`.

Generating files to the source tree is not a good choice anyways, since it prevents you from setting up multiple build dirs based on the same source dir in a way that has all of the projects work properly. (In this case it happens to not cause any problems, since the logic for generating the file is independent of the configuration.)

Here's what I'd use

```
set(GENERATED_SOURCE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/sample2.cpp)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT sample2.cpp
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sample.cpp ${GENERATED_SOURCE}
        DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sample.cpp)
add_executable(grpc-app-main main.cpp ${GENERATED_SOURCE})
```

Note: I also changed the use of `cp` to using [`cmake -E copy`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-E-arg-copy) to be platform independent here.

Answer (score 0):

If sample.cpp isn't in `/Users/AAA/clion/BigPro/cmake-build-debug/grpc-demo`, you either have to adjust the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` of the custom command, or use absolute paths for the files. For example, instead of `COMMAND cp sample.cpp sample2.cpp`, do `COMMAND cp "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sample.cpp" sample2.cpp`.

Comment: There's no guarantee everyone always adds a `project` command on every level of their cmake project tree. `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` only works with a `project` command in the current `CMakeLists.txt`. This is why I recommend using `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` instead.

Comment: @fabian I wrote this from what they showed in their question post. If the dependency file is in the project root, I don't see why not use `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`.

Comment: Some person in the future may read this question, see your answer and apply the logic to their project where the `project` command happens to be missing from the `CMakeLists.txt` file they're modifying. Since `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` would work even in that scenario, I don't see a reason to use `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` instead.